# Redirect specific virtual urls to index.html

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i currently try to rederict my language specific virtual url's to the index.html. 
sadly it won't work so i aks you here.

on my index.html page i set virtual urls with the history api such like this:

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'de');
```

so that works perfectly fine, but when i enter the url manually, the server tries to open the index.php/de, which dosent exists.

my idea was to redirect all virtual urls for let's say "/de/" and "/en/" to the index.html file and keep the initial url. i will then do the navigation and content loading stuff in the index.html with js.

- domain.com/de -> opens the index.html and keeps the original url
- domain.com/en -> opens the index.html and keeps the original url

**my mod_rewrite code:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/de?$" "/index.html"
```

unfortunately this code redirect nothing. my server log say that the domain.com/de can not be found.

any ideas to fix this?

cheers
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule` removes the leading slash when you're in a htaccess.
So you're trying to match a wrong path (that's why it does not work).

Also, get rid of `"` in the rule and add `L` flag after.

You can replace your code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:de|en)$ /index.html [L]
```

Note: make sure *mod_rewrite* is **enabled** (and *htaccess* files allowed) in your Apache config

---

EDIT: taking your comment below into consideration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:de|en)(?:$|/.+) /index.html [L]
```

Comment: thank you Justin, now it works. one last question: how do i have to change the rewrite rule to allow something like this: domain.com/en/bla?

Comment: You're welcome. To answer your question, you can see my edited answer. This new rule allows `http://domain.com/en` or `http://domain.com/en/something` but not `http://domain.com/en/` (same with `de`)